# Using nestjs/axios GET request set encoding for xml

Tags: axios, nestjs

I am trying to retrieve a XML via axios (for nestjs) from an external HTTP service. Unfortunately the encoding does not seem to work correctly, because the special characters (ü, ö, ä, etc.) are not are not delivered correctly. How can I set the encoding correctly in the header of a GET request, so that it works ? When I open the url directly in the browser, the encoding works correctly. For XML parsing I use the fast-xml-parser.

```
return this.httpService.get(`mycoolurl`,
  {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
    },
  },
  )
  .pipe(map((res) => { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I was able to find a solution. Call the API with responseType arraybuffer and use the [TextDecoder](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html) to decode the data correctly. In NestJS you can use "transformResponse" for this:

```
{
  responseType: 'arraybuffer',
  transformResponse: [
  (data) => {
    const decoder = new TextDecoder('ISO-8859-1');
    return decoder.decode(data);
   },
  ],
},
```